# testing rails controllers file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

This is my create action in ParticipationConsent controller.

**ParticipationConsent#create**

```
 def create
    @participation_consent =   @project.participation_consent.new(params[:participation_consent])
    @participation_consent.user = current_user
    @participation_consent.confirmed = true
    @participation_consent.save!
 end
```

And this is my test for create method

```
context 'get :create' do 
it 'should be success for approved creative' do 
  sign_in @approved_creative
  expect{
    get :create, :project => @project.id, :participation_consent => { :project_id => @project.id, :user_id => @approved_creative.id, :confirmed_in => false }
  }.to change(ParticipationConsent, :count).by(1)
  response.should redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

When I run the test file,I encounter this error.

```
Failure/Error: get :create, :project => @project.id, :participation_consent => { :project_id => @project.id, :user_id => @approved_creative.id, :confirmed_in => false }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:project=>1, :participation_consent => {:project_id=>1, :user_id=>2, :confirmed_in=>false}, :controller=>"participation_consents", :action=>"create"}
```

Do you know how can I deal with it?

Edit-1:

**routes.rb**

```
 project_participation_consents POST   /projects/:project_id/participation_consents(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"participation_consents"}
```

Comment: could you post your `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is you are sending a GET request for a create action, which is a POST action, change `get` to `post`

Also, where is `@project` coming from in your controller code? You should be loading the project from the id in params, presumably.

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
```